# Is there a better word for "punishing" or "demotivating" in this context?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I've used the following sentences recently and I don't know how to express myself in this context without doing it too *strongly*.

> Now I was thinking to reward those who put a bit more effort and do a
>   proper edit without **punishing** them with a reject. This could lead to
>   fewer rejected edits and hopefully more quality suggested edits.

The word *punishing* is too strong in my opinion. I was thinking about using *demotivating* but this does not nail it neither.

It is not really a *punishment* and it is not supposed to *demotivate*, so those words are not really appropriate, I think.

**What can you suggest? Can you fill in the gap?**

Comment: *discouraging*.   Everyone hates having sincere effort discarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the word you are looking for is *discourage*, although it is similar to *demotivate*.

Definition of *discourage* by Google: "cause (someone) to lose confidence or enthusiasm." Usage examples: "I don't want to discourage you, but I don't think it's such a good idea," "she was discouraged by his hostile tone."

So your statement would read:
"Now I was thinking to reward those who put a bit more effort and do a proper edit without **discouraging** them with a reject. This could lead to fewer rejected edits and hopefully more quality suggested edits."

edit: didn't notice that **stevesliva** already suggested this word.

Comment: True stevesliva did suggest that in a comment. I upvoted, but could not do more. *discouraging* is what I needed. Until now I thought it was used to make someone not do something. That's a new usage I learned here. Thank you guys.